# New Mapbox iOS SDK generating problem, When I install any pod they show problem

Tags: cocoapods, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-ios

I'm using Mapbox SDK, and when installing new pods, It is pod will be showing errors. I change pods and it showing error again and again. I was using these pods, pod **'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.1' pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.35.0' pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift', '~> 0.11'**

I updated pods too pod **'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.3' pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.37.0' pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift', '~> 0.11'**
It showing post again and again.
[image][image]

Comment: The errors you've shared seem to reference SDKs that are not included in the three `pod`s you reference in your Podfile (specifically `MapboxVision`). Are you installing additional dependencies that aren't included in the above screenshots?

Comment: @riastrad no I'm not using MapboxVision in my project

Comment: If that’s the case @EngrMuhammadNaeemAkram, then you can remove the second and third from last items in your Podfile. The problem appears to be the result of using a version of MapboxNavigation that has an incompatible version of a dependency with MapboxVision. If you remove the MapboxVision pod, I expect the error will go away.

Comment: Yes @riastrad I do that few days before, and error goes away.

Comment: For Latest Mapbox SDKs we need to put .netrc into user's root folder and not in project's root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed last two pods. As they generate error.